# Add a Link to a DataTable Column

Tags: datatables

Hi I am trying to add a link within a datatable column. I am bringing in the information via an array of objects. Here is my implementation. How can I add a new column with a link?
I want the link text to be something generic such as "Link" or maybe put in an icon such as

```html
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></a>
```

```js
var createDataTable = function(responseObj){
    adminInfoTable = $('#adminInfoTable').DataTable({
        data: responseObj,
             "columns":[
                    {data:"Date"},
                    {data:"FullName"},
                    {data:"CrossPartyName"},
                    {data:"streetAddress"},
                    {data:"City"},
                    {data:"State"},
                    {data:"Zip5"}
            ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out `"columns":[
                        {data:"Date"},
                        {data:"FullName"},
                        {data:"CrossPartyName"},
                        {data:"streetAddress"},
                        {data:"City"},
                        {data:"State"},
                        {data:"Zip5"},
                        {data:"PlatBookPageUrl"}
                ],

```
            // sets custom render function for the 7th row PlatBookPageUrl
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": 7,
                "data": "PlatBookPageUrl",
                "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                  return '<a target="_blank" href="'+data+'"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></a>';
                }
              } ],`
```

Comment: Thats great. Perhaps you could setup a fiddle, demonstrating your solution? Then, consider accepting your own answer (by marking it as accepted) - perhaps it will help other people in the future.

Comment: Hey @williamHowley, there is a **√** under your answer, you just need to click on. I am not totally clear on the rules, perhaps you cannot now you only have 1 rep.